# Swift FBSDKLogin Swift 3 AppDelegate update

Tags: swift, facebook-ios-sdk, swift3

I am currently implementing Facebook login in my app, and I just came to notice that after the Swift 3 update, the code in AppDelegate has slightly changed since the last time I added Facebook login to my app. I am struggling with this function (this is Swift 2.2) here:

```
    func application(application:UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, 

openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

After the 3.0 update, the function looks like this:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

}
```

How should I make it work in 3.0, considering there is no 'sourceApplication' nor an 'annotation'?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the given answer work? You haven't accepted it.

Comment: @David It did! I completely forgot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally forgot to accept it. Thank you so much, it worked!